# How can i display a list in react native using fetch?

Tags: javascript, php, response, display, react-native-flatlist

The data i sent it from fetch and php ,  it's can be load and the result of the flat liste is  none and it was only the text i wrote also i use flatliste but nothing in on the screen , i think the problem is in array sat and how to use value , key and item

```
import ajax from './fetchdata.js'
export class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { sat: [] };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
   const sat = await ajax.fetchset();
   console.log(this.state.sat);
   this.setState({sat});
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.h2text}>
              Black Order
            </Text>
           <FlatList
                data={this.state.sat}
                keyExtractor={item => item.idC}
                renderItem={ ({item}) => {
                        return (
                                    <View style={{ flex : 1, flexDirection : "row" }}>
                                    <View style={{ flex : .6 }}>
                                        <Text style={{ fontSize : 20 , textColor:'red'}}>{item.nom}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={{ flex : .4 }}>
                                            <Text style={{ fontSize : 20 , textColor:'red' }}>{item.adresse} points</Text>
                                    </View>
                                      </View>
                              );
                        }

                      }

                       />

          </View>
    );
  }
}
*/




export default Home;



////////fetchdata.js

 export default {
    async fetchset() {
        try {
                let response = await fetch('http://localhost/APP/Chauffeur/Backendapp/api/Traitement/AffichageStation.php');
                let responseJsonData = await response.json();
                console.log("done")
                return responseJsonData;

            }
        catch(e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
}
```

exepected a liste of data the adresse and nom , but the message is only the the text Black Order

Comment: whats the output of `console.log(this.state.sat);`? EDIT: change that to `console.log(sat);` and let us know the output

Comment: the result is none , like nothing i display in console

Comment: Not even "done"?

Comment: nope there is nothing

Comment: ```php <?php             session_start();
              include_once "../../config/Database.php";
              include_once "../../models/Affectation.php";
              $Database = new Database();
              $db = $Database->connect();
              $Affectation = new Affectation($db);

              $Affectation->idCH='105';
              $results=$Affectation->chau();

              echo $results;




 ?>
``` this how i use php

Comment: How can I show an array from a fetch() on a <FlatList> using php ?